# When using multiplicative hashing h(k) = (k * A) % M is there a best choice for A?

Tags: hash, multiplication

I'm using multiplicative hashing with different values of M being random 64 bit primes. Should also use a multiplicative factor A? what are the best choices for A?

Comment: All numbers 0 < A < M are equally good provided M is prime.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff well, powers of two will just shift the number....

Comment: Yes.  Hashing does not imply encrypting :-)  Do you need to hide number `k`?

Comment: Not encrypting but mix it a bit